# Losing type specificity when passing a child interface that extends a parent interface into a generatic interface

Tags: typescript

Trying to create a dynamic interface that gives me the properties of a Shape based on its type.

For example:

```js
interface Attributes {
  fill:string|number;
  width:string|number;
  height:string|number;
  stroke:string|number;
  strokeWidth:string|number;
}

interface Circle extends Shape {
  cy:string|number;
  cx:string|number;
  r:string|number;
}

interface Square extends Shape {
  x:string|number;
  y:string|number;
}

interface Polygon extends Shape {
  points:string|number;
}


interface Shape extends Partial<Attributes> {
  [key:string]:string|number|undefined;
}

type ShapeAttributes<T extends Partial<Attributes>, S> = {
  [k in keyof T]:S
}

type ShapeState = {
  currentShapeState:ShapeAttributes<Shape, string|number | undefined>;
} 

const circle:ShapeAttributes<Circle, string|number> = {
  fill:"0",
  stroke:"0",
  strokeWidth:"0",
  width:"0",
  height:"0",
  cx:"0",
  cy:"0",
  r:"0",

}

const Square:ShapeAttributes<Square, string|number> = {
  fill:"0",
  stroke:"0",
  strokeWidth:"0",
  width:"0",
  height:"0",
  x:"0",
  y:"0",
}

function shapeState():ShapeState {
 
  return {
    currentShapeState:circle
  }; 
  
}

const shape = shapeState();
const innerShape = shape.currentShapeState;
```

I understand that if I replace `Shape` with `Circle` or `Square` it's kind of what I want, but then it's hard coded and not dynamic.
When I hover over in the TS playground, `shape.currentShapeState`, the tooltip gives me `(property) currentShapeState: ShapeAttributes<Shape, string | number | undefined>`.
I know that my function's return type is ShapeState which defines ShapeState as `ShapeAttributes<Shape, string | number | undefined>`. Was wondering if there was a way to narrow it down based on the value's type I pass it (i.e. currentShapeState is `circle` so I was hoping that innerShape would have the type `ShapeAttributes<Circle,string|number>`, if even possible at all.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-m48E22nvn2qbA6dVF3o-qpgeImXX6qLWnDejLzorDEXbZM5jnV4cndcl+ELm7LaUKjUGifU7flAqi-2OBGiQNJQVQFgoAgRITEiVIygJNEoAZABpKAyiJSEuTQnk+UQ-IAApjFwAArehcMiBlyjI1CygASlZdUIDdMEiOI0o0Kqb4gLAECQDAogbTtaB8NozdBN9e550g5jWTmN0PQgL0fWgegkEzEZBC8Phk0oIVfBXdMBOmR1UCMyJlKgESBAMiAOTAVoYC9EyzKgAA6V13XGRTxOgPggA)

Comment: Nope, there is no way you can get it to work like that.